# Deserializing JSON produces default class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am deserializing an Object using this code

```
PlayerData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(response.Content);
```

My UserData class is as follows

```
    public class UserData : BindableBase
    {
        public string UID { get; set; }
        public string UDID { get; set; }
        public object liveID { get; set; }
        public int timeLastSeen { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string session { get; set; }
        public int serverTime { get; set; }
        public int PremiumCurrency { get; set; }

        public UserData()
        {

        }
    }
```

When it deserializes I get an object returned as if I had just called `new UserData()` but if I remove the `: BindableBase` from the class definition it deserializes correctly. I guess this is because the base class contains some properties that arent in the JSON but I just want those ignored. Is there a setting for this?

The BindableBase class is as follows

```
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
[DataContract]
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON is as follows

```
{
    "UID": "4",
    "UDID": "",
    "liveID": null,
    "timeLastSeen": 1392730436,
    "country": "GB",
    "username": "User4",
    "PremiumCurrency": "20",
    "session": "5c8583311732fa816e333dc5e6426d65",
    "serverTime": 1392730437
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your `BindableBase` class code? Cannot reproduce your issue. Also, do you use lase version of `Json.Net` or some specific?

Comment: Edited question with the base class code. It's the latest version of JSON.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear enough to answer that the problem is in `DataContract` attribute of base class. Easy way to fix it is to decorate properties of derived class with `DataMember` attributes.